# Обработка нажатий в ListView

Tags: android, listview, click

Есть обычный ListVew в android.. Каждый элемент состоит из текста и картинки. 
перехватываю клик с помощью OnItemClickListener.

Вопрос: Как определить, что клик по элементу был на картинке?

P.S по возможности без создавания своих Адаптеров

Comment: А уточните пожалуйста как вы назначаете OnClickListner и на какой элемент(желательно с кодом)

Comment: никак не определить без своего адаптера.

Comment: А как вы формируете элемент списка из текста и картинки без применения своего кастомного адаптера?

Comment: Навесьте OnClickListner в адаптере на вьюхи и удалите OnItemClickListner из фрагмента